# What are the implications of the letting an outlook “website” configure my settings

Tags: microsoft-outlook, default-settings

I am regularly asked by MS Outlook “Allow this website to configure *<e-mail-address>* settings?”, with reference to our company e-mail. I always refuse, as it is unclear to me what the implications are. I also do not tick the “Don’t ask again” box, as it is unclear whether it then always applies my answer or just does what it feels like.

How can I find out which settings would be affected, and how does Outlook treat the “Don’t ask again” box?

I am using Outlook 2007 but a broader answer is welcome.

Comment: "it is unclear whether it then always applies my answer or just does what it feels"  -- `Don't ask me again` means "don't ask me again in the future, just use what I choose now instead".

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Have you seen that documented? It is certainly what I think it ought to mean!